# Basic ToDo application issue with Flask+AngularJS

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

for last two days I`m trying to figure out how to setup angularjs with flask backend. I have this code for my **init**.py file

```
    1 from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, send_file, request
  2 from flask.ext.triangle import Triangle
  3 
  4 app = Flask(__name__, static_path='/static')
  5 Triangle(app)
  6 app.debug() = True
  7 
  8 @app.route('/')
  9 def homepage():
 10     return render_template('home.html')
 11 
 12 @app.route('/todo')
 13 def todos():
 14     return render_template('todo.html')
 15 
 16 if __name__ == "__main__":
 17     app.run()
```

and this basic todo application, that is working when i try it on my computer. When I upload it to my server and try to go to /todo url i get 500 Internal Server Error.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Todo</h2>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.length|angular}} remaining</span> [ <a href="" ng-click="archive()">archive</a> ]
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
                <span class="done-{{todo.done|angular}}">{{todo.text|angular}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
            <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" size="30" placeholder="add new todo here">
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>

        function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.todos = [
    {text:'learn angular', done:true},
    {text:'build an angular app', done:false}];

  $scope.addTodo = function() {
    $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
    $scope.todoText = '';
  };

  $scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
      count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
    return count;
  };

  $scope.archive = function() {
    var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
    $scope.todos = [];
    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
      if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
    });
  };
}
    </script>

        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/js/angular.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to fix it ? I tried placing angular code in app.js in /static/js folder but still not working

Comment: And what does your error log in the console show?

Answer (score 0):

first run you app in debug

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

this should provide more info about your error

second iirc Triangle requires you to pass a angular filter to your angular template tags

```
<li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
            <span class="done-{{todo.done|angular}}">{{todo.text|angular}}</span>
        </li>
```

Comment: where i will see the debug output ? I can`t find on the web when i can find the output. I`ve added the angular filter but it is still not working

Comment: on the url that generates your error... on your webserver it is probably not doing `app.run` so you dont see it... to fix this you can do `app.debug = True` further up in your script

Comment: app.run is working because I can go to / which is my home page and everything is ok. The problem is somewhere in the /todo url.  i added the app.debug  but still cannot figure out how to see the result